# Getter isn't defined for the object

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to setState using the passed class instance and accessing the member values but it is giving me the error of getter not defined on the object. But the same is working in initState method.

This is for passing the value when the user closes the ShowDialog. I tried setting up the getters and also changing the class members from private to public.

```dart
class MyReaction {
   IconData _icon;
   String _text;
   MyReaction(this._icon, this._text);
   IconData get iconD => this._icon;
   String get textV => this._text;
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  MyReaction _myreaction = new MyReaction(Icons.thumb_up, 'Like');

  IconData _myreactionIcon;
  String _myreactionText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = new ScrollController();
    _myreactionIcon = _myreaction.iconD; //It works here!!
    _myreactionText  = _myreaction.textV;
  }

  FlatButton.icon(
   icon:Icon(this._myreactionIcon, size: 24.0), 
   onPressed: () {
    showDemoDialog<MyReaction>(
                context: context,
                child: SimpleDialog(
                  title: const Text('Your Reaction'),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    DialogDemoItem(
                      icon: Icons.account_circle,
                      color: Colors.black87,
                      text: 'username@gmail.com',
                      onPressed: () {
                        MyReaction  _reaction = new MyReaction(Icons.account_circle, 'Like');
                        Navigator.pop(context, _reaction);
                      },
                    ),
                  ]
                )
    );
   },
  );


 void showDemoDialog<MyReaction>({ BuildContext context, Widget child }) {
    showDialog<MyReaction>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => child,
    )
    .then<void>((MyReaction value) { // The value passed to Navigator.pop() or null.
      if (value != null) {
        setState(() {
          _myreactionIcon = value.iconD; //Does not work here
          _myreactionText = value.textV;});
        // _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        //   content: Text('You selected: $value'),
        ));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I am expecting the value inside the showDialog method to be assignable to the state variables. But value.iconD is giving getter not defined error. What mistake am I doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have added a generic type paramter to your method `showDemoDialog` which shadows (hides) your definition of the class `MyReaction`.

This generic type parameter is not actually used in your method and thus can be removed.

Just define your method like this:

```dart
void showDemoDialog({ BuildContext context, Widget child }) {
  showDialog<MyReaction>(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) => child)
    .then((MyReaction value) { // The value passed to Navigator.pop() or null.
      if (value != null) {
        setState(() {
          _myreactionIcon = value.iconD; // Does now work
          _myreactionText = value.textV;
        });
       }
    }
  );

}
```